# recreating camera object after error 100 (camera server died)

Tags: android, android-camera

I have classic android app with camera preview (common implem that can be found in many tutorials [marakana etc.]) that is supposed to take picture in a given time interval. Threading and killing threads is done, errors such `"method called after release"` are handled. But sometimes the well-known error `100` occurs. I accepted the fact that it happens and tried to handle it too. I implemented `ErrorCallback` and its `onError` method where the current camera object is released and instantiated a new one as written in official documentation.

But (with no surprise) it is not enough. New camera is maybe wrongly allocated because an message `"CameraDemo has been exited unexpectedly"` appears now.
I've read many docs and examples in hope, that a proper proceeding will be somewhere explained but no one has such problem apparently. So I would like to ask what else should I do beside releasing and creating new camera? Here is the code:

```
ErrorCallback CEC = new ErrorCallback()
{
    public void onError(int error, Camera camera)
    {
        Log.d("CameraDemo", "camera error detected");
        if(error == Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED)
        {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "attempting to reinstantiate new camera");
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release(); //written in documentation...
            camera = null;              
            camera = Camera.open();

        }
    }
};
```

Shortly - if I release and recreate camera in `onError` callback then `RuntimeException` Method called after release (takePicture) is raised. So should I somehow assign the surface holder to camera again or recreate the surface holder too?

It would be enough to direct me e.g. to some forums, where it is described or solved, etc. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Please share

Answer (score 0):

In my app to handle the camere i use this :

```
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
if(mCamera == null)
    mCamera = getCameraInstance():
}


public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
 mCamera = null;
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(yourPreviewCb);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    mCamera.autoFocus(yourAutoFocusCB);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO
    }
    return mCamera;
}
```

The mCamera = null in the getCameraInstance() is just to be sure there is no camera running at all.

I think you need to recreate a complete camera, not just open it with the

```
camera.open();
```

Set this in the onResume or in the error callback, depending on your needs.

Comment: Warning! When `surfaceChanged` is invoked when the surface changes (size for example), if the `Camera` object is not remade IF the screen has changed size it will result in the Error 100. This is crashing due to the camera screen being modified (on older devices the camera sometimes lags and gets stuck resulting in an altered preview screen size). - In other words, be sure to keep an eye on `surfaceChanged`, it is also prone to creating the Error 100.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it, here is a sample of code, think you get the idea:

```
private Camera camera;

// code...

public Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    // code...
    camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
            if(error == Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
                releaseCamera();
                startCamera();
            }
        }
    });
    return camera;
}

protected void startCamera() {
    if(getCamera() == null)
        setCamera(getCameraInstance());
    refreshCamera();
}

protected void releaseCamera() {
    if (getCamera() != null) {
        getCamera().release();
        setCamera(null);
    }
}

public Camera getCamera() {
    return camera;
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    this.camera = camera;
}
```